# deployment failure due error loading instance of CacheControlPhaseListener

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am unable to deploy my application in eclipse and getting this error:

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: jndi:/server/application/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'com.mycompany.fs.wbdb.server.CacheControlPhaseListener': javax.faces.FacesException: com.mycompany.fs.wbdb.server.CacheControlPhaseListener

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>/Bundle</base-name>
            <var>bundle</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener id="nocache">com.mycompany.fs.wbdb.server.CacheControlPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Check if the class is on the classpath. One suggestion is to use a standalone Tomcat (not through Eclipse), export your WAR file and start tomcat and look at the logs if there are any errors.

Comment: it should be on classpath..but how do i check that?